# Tkinter display grid with a scrollbar

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, scrollbar

I'm looking to make a list of buttons in a tkinter interface, with the ability to navigate between the rows of buttons with a scrollbar.

This is a bit of a "bastard" code in the sense that scrollbars are not often used in this case according to the examples I've seen on the internet. I have tried the grid and pack methods in tkinter, but without more success.

I'm having trouble adding a scrollbar with a cursor size that matches the size of the data. Either the scrollbar does not activate or the size of the slider does not match the data.

The code I made is the following. When running it, we notice that the scrollbar on the right does not work. To fix the problem, you just have to remove from the code "yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set", but then the size of the scrollbar is no longer adapted to the list, which is not convenient for me because we often arrive outside the area of the buttons. Do you have an idea of the source of the problem?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# ----------------------------------------------- Frame of the window ----------------------------------------------- #
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Grid Layout")

# Adjust window size
root.geometry("1110x520")
# set minimum window size value
root.minsize(1110, 520)
# set maximum window size value
root.maxsize(1110, 520)

# Save, Load and Exit button in top left
frame = Frame(root)

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# --------------------------------------------- Structure of the window --------------------------------------------- #
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# Create the 4 main grids: right bottom, right top, left bottom, and left top
right_bottom = tk.Frame(root, bd=0, relief="solid", bg="white")
right_top = tk.Frame(root, bd=0, relief="solid", bg="white")
left_center = tk.Frame(root, bd=0, relief="solid", bg="white")
left_bottom = tk.Frame(root, bd=0, relief="solid", bg="white")
left_top = tk.Frame(root, bd=0, relief="solid", bg="white")
center_top = tk.Frame(root, bd=0, relief="solid", bg="white")

# Position the 4 main grids in the root window
right_top.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=10, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
right_bottom.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=10, ipadx=5, ipady=5, rowspan=2, columnspan=2)
left_top.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=10, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
left_center.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=10, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
left_bottom.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=10, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
center_top.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)



# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# ---------------------------------------------- Création de la zone ------------------------------------------------ #
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# Create the scrollbar
scrollbar = Scrollbar(right_bottom)
scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")

# Create the canvas
right_bottom_area = tk.Canvas(right_bottom, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, height=300, width=800, background="white")
right_bottom_area.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="e")

# Connect the scrollbar to the canvas
scrollbar.config(command=right_bottom_area.yview)

# Set the scroll region of the canvas to the bounding box of all the items in the canvas
right_bottom_area.config(scrollregion=right_bottom_area.bbox("all"))

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# ------------------------------------------------- Lignes impaires ------------------------------------------------- #
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
text_field = "Test"

for i in range(0, 15, 2):
    for j in range(5):
        cell = tk.Button(right_bottom_area, text=text_field, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, height=2, width=10, fg='black', font=("TkDefaultFont",10,"bold"))
        right_bottom_area.create_window(j * 100, i * 50, window=cell, anchor="nw")

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# -------------------------------------------------- Lignes paires -------------------------------------------------- #
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
for i in range(1, 15, 2):
    for j in range(5):
        cell = tk.Button(right_bottom_area, text=text_field, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, height=2, width=10, fg='blue', bg='yellow')
        right_bottom_area.create_window(j * 100, i * 50-10, window=cell, anchor="nw")

root.mainloop()
```

I put an "ipady" and "ipadx" in the "right_top" box, but the buttons are stuck on the top left (without any margin), would you have an idea to correct this?

Thank you very much,
Partodiam

Comment: You should update the *scrollregion* after adding those buttons, not before.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I always try to segment my code but I didn't see this error happening because of it. Any idea for the ipad margin ?